# Swift init(), defining custom init is it overriding?

Tags: ios, swift

I have some confusion over this:

```
class Person {

    var name: String
    var age: Int

    init(){

        name = “Tim”
        age = 30
    }


}
```

A basic custom init. What exactly is the code below doing?:

```
init(){
  //Code here
}
```

It's not an override because we don't use `override func init()`. Someone said it's actually calling a default init method that comes with the class. If that's the case then what do the curly brackets do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you haven't subclassed from `NSObject`, there is no `init()` method to override. Hence why you don't need it in this case.

In this case, nothing else is called when you call your `init()` method, there are no other default initializers. The curly brackets are there simply because you're not accepting any arguments to your init method. You could for example accept some arguments:

```
init(withName name: String, andAge age: Int) {
  self.name = name
  self.age = age
}
```

And call it like so:

`Person(withName: "Chris", andAge: 23)`

Comment: Thanks. But is this code block defining the init function then?

Comment: Yep, you've just defined the designated initializer for your class. Have a read up on [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html).

Answer (score 1):

Swift provides a default initializer for any structure or class that provides default values for all of its properties and does not provide at least one initializer itself. The default initializer simply creates a new instance with all of its properties set to their default values.

You can customize the initialization process with input parameters and optional property types, or by assigning constant properties during initialization.

You can provide initialization parameters as part of an initializer’s definition, to define the types and names of values that customize the initialization process. Initialization parameters have the same capabilities and syntax as function and method parameters.